# Artifactory retrieve latest and ignore maven-metadata.xml

Tags: maven, groovy, get, artifactory

I'm trying to retrieve the latest version of a artifact from artifactory, but there is a file "maven-metadata.xml" in the target directory that is always being returned.

Is there a way for the request to exclude the file? My current request looks as follows:

"https://artifactory/api/storage/pathtodirectory?lastModified"

This returns the maven-metadata.xml file, I tried modifying the request to:

"https://artifactory/api/storage/pathtodirectory?lastModified?archiveType!=xml"

But that didn't exclude the file.

Comment: Why is this tagged groovy?

Answer (score 1):

You have the option of retrieving the latest artifact which was modified, while also excluding patterns of files, using [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI).
Here's how you do it:

```
jfrog rt s repo-name/path/to/directory/ --sort-by modified --sort-order desc --limit 1 --exclusions "*maven-metadata.xml"
```

Notice that the source path argument ends with a slash (...directory/), to indicate that yuo wish to retrieve the content of the *directory* folder in Artifactory.
You can modify the source path argument and also the value of the *--exclusions* option to include wildcards, and also change the value of the *--limit* option to return the X last modified artifacts.
Once you're satisfied with the output, and you want to download the artifact, simply replace *jfrog rt s* with *jfrog rt dl*.